# Data binding sync with keyboard events

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a TextBox bounded to a property and when is pressed "enter" in this TextBox, a method is called to update some other variables.

if I try to use the value of the bounded property in this method, its value still has the old one.

I need to exit the TextBox to get this property updated.

There is a way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textbox bindings have a default [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `LostFocus`. Just use `PropertyChanged` instead if you want updates every time the text changes.

eg.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

If you only want to update the binding when enter is pressed, then you can use `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` and update the binding manually in code behind.

eg

```
BindingExpression binding = myTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
binding.UpdateSource();
```

Comment: This is something to use with care. There is a way to update all the bindings before call my method.

Comment: As I said, if you want to do it manually use `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`. I've added some example code behind.